# How to use different tab settings in different projects in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

The Visual Studio options dialog allows you to set tab preferences (size, insert-spaces, etc.) on a per-language basis. But I am regularly working on a couple of c# projects with different settings for these values.

Is there a way to override the global settings on a per-project basis, or at least toggle between them easily?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another approach may be through the extensibility API: it should be possible to write a macro or add-in that changes these settings.

E.g. to change the tab size to 6, use the following:

```
    DTE.Properties("TextEditor", "CSharp").Item("TabSize").Value = 6
```

Here's a link that explains how to find out the names of the properties: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555445

Answer (score 2):

You can open visual studio with a special "reset" settings file which overrides the default settings. Using this method it is possible to create two shortcuts, one with each tab setting. Details are [here](http://mkdot.net/blogs/lz/archive/2009/03/31/visual-studio-how-to-work-with-different-tab-settings-per-project.aspx).

Comment: Your link goes to 404

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't do that on a per-project basis.
But, with `Tools/Import and Export Settings...` you can export each settings in a file and you could import the one that fits your current project.

Answer (score 1):

Visual studio 2017 adds [.editorconfig](http://editorconfig.org/) support, which is very handy for such settings.